# Making a query for travel agency project

Tags: mysql, join

I need to print all the flight numbers and departure/arrival times of all flights that depart from (e.g ABC) and arrive at (e.g XYZ) airport on 3/3/12.

*Flight* table:

```
flight_number(primary key),
airline_name(foreign key), 
weekdays,
departure_airport,
arrival_airport,
departure_time,
arrival_time, 
no_of_seats)
```

*Airport* table:

```
airport_code(primary key),
airport_name,
airline_name(foreign key),
address_state,
address_city,
address_telno
```

I have done this using a *subquery*, but need to accomplish this using *JOINS*  instead. 
Here is the *subquery* I used:

```
select flight_number,departure_time,arrival_time 
from (
    select * from flight
    where(flight.departure_airport='ABC' AND flight.arrival_airport='XYZ')
);
```

I have tried using the following query:

```
select flight_number,weekdays,departure_airport,arrival_airport,departure_time,arrival_‌​time,no_of_seats 
FROM (SELECT * FROM flight 
INNER JOIN airport ON flight.departure_airport = airport.airport_code 
WHERE (airport.airport_code = '08' OR airport.address_city='RUH')) ;
```

I get the error: `invalid number at line 4 –`

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors? This site is to help you, not do all the work.

Comment: You don't have a departure/arrival date in any of the tables, or does departure/arrival time in the flight table have the date as well?

Comment: I have done this using sub query:

select flight_number,departure_time,arrival_time
from (select * from flight\
where(flight.departure_airport='ABC' AND 
flight.arrival_airport='XYZ'));
I need to do it using joins. Secondly I am unable to edit it to make it more readable :/

Comment: @LenaR Is the `airport_code` field an integer or string in the database? Your query has it as a string, just remove the `'` around *08* in your original query if that column is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select flight_number, departure_time 
from flight left join Airport on fligt.airline_name = Airport.airline_name 
where date(departure_time) = '2012-03-03' and airport_name = 'your_airport_name' 
and departure_airport = 'your_dept_port' and 
arrival_airport = 'your_arrival_port'
```